# Could not open input file: yii when i start rbac migration

Tags: yii2, migration, mamp

I'm new on mac, I'm trying to make migration for rbac, but i have error

```
Could not open input file: yii
```

[image]

I read a lot of answers and tried everything, but nothing suits me
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

as your `ls` statement shows, there's no yii file. (yii.bat doesn't count)
you need to run the init script again to generate it

```
php init
```